# Loop through URL using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have looked at a few questions but none of the answers seem to fit. I am building a webscraper tool as a personal project. I have figured out the loops to get rider data for the Vuelta 2022 however I need to loop through all the urls for each stage. For some reason, the url loop is taking the last number in the range. My gut feeling is the formatting so I am trying to play around with that but no luck

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

for j in range (1,10):
    url = (f"https://www.lavuelta.es/en/rankings/stage-{j}")
    page = requests.get(url)
    urlt = page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlt)
    rider_rank_list = []
for i in range (1,11):
#create list of riders
    results = soup.select_one(f"body > main > div > section.ranking.classements > div > div > div.js-tabs-wrapper.js-tabs-bigwrapper > div > div > div > div > div.js-spinner-wrapper > div > div.sticky-scroll > table > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td.runner.is-sticky > a ")

        
#create rider rank list
    rrank = soup.select_one(f"body > main > div > section.ranking.classements > div > div > div.js-tabs-wrapper.js-tabs-bigwrapper > div > div > div > div > div.js-spinner-wrapper > div > div.sticky-scroll > table > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td:nth-child(1)")


#create stage name
    stage = str.replace(str.title(url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]),'-',' ')

    rider_rank_list.append((str(stage),str.strip(results.text), str.strip(rrank.text)))


    
print(rider_rank_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(rider_rank_list, columns=['stage','rider','rank'], index=None)
print(df)

df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Is your indentation correctly formatted?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips to debug your code.

Comment: @BeRT2me. I don't think so, I think I need to learn how to indent properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed indentation, with small changes

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

rider_rank_list = []

for j in range (1,10):
    url = (f"https://www.lavuelta.es/en/rankings/stage-{j}")
    page = requests.get(url)
    urlt = page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlt)
    
    for i in range (1,11):
        #create list of riders
        results = soup.select_one(f"body > main > div > section.ranking.classements > div > div > div.js-tabs-wrapper.js-tabs-bigwrapper > div > div > div > div > div.js-spinner-wrapper > div > div.sticky-scroll > table > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td.runner.is-sticky > a ")

        if results != None: 
        
            #create rider rank list
            rrank = soup.select_one(f"body > main > div > section.ranking.classements > div > div > div.js-tabs-wrapper.js-tabs-bigwrapper > div > div > div > div > div.js-spinner-wrapper > div > div.sticky-scroll > table > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td:nth-child(1)")

            #create stage name
            stage = str.replace(str.title(url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]),'-',' ')
        
            rider_rank_list.append((str(stage),str.strip(results.text), str.strip(rrank.text)))


    
print(rider_rank_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(rider_rank_list, columns=['stage','rider','rank'], index=None)
print(df)

df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: this is perfect. What was the indentation issue? I guess i need to learn code/loop formatting. Thank you for the answer

Comment: you are welcome. I moved second for loop inside the first one. Check out nested loop: https://pynative.com/python-nested-loops/

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from other answers and added complete easier and probably more readable table format solution to your question:

```
import pandas as pd

al=pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(2,19): # Stage only started from 2 to 18
    url = f"https://www.lavuelta.es/en/rankings/stage-{i}"
    df=pd.read_html(url)[0]

    # Taking top 10 rider ie. top 10 ranked riders only
    df=df[["Rider"]][:10]

    # Renaming using "Rider" with stage number
    df.columns=[f"Stage - {i} - Rider"]

    # Adding all Rider column horizontally
    al=pd.concat([al,df],axis=1)


al.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```